# How to resolve orderTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, sharingrecordcollection

For one of challenges in advance apex specialist ,i am getting this error which is really confusing me, if you can help

`There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 801Dn000000US3rIAG; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, orderTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 01tDn000004FRo4IAG; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, product2Trigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Class.Product2Helper.PostAlerts: line 77, column 1 Class.Product2Helper.AfterUpdate: line 55, column 1 Trigger.product2Trigger: line 6, column 1: [] Class.OrderHelper.RollUpOrderItems: line 47, column 1 Class.OrderHelper.AfterUpdate: line 19, column 1 Trigger.orderTrigger: line 5, column 1: []`

here is OrderTrigger

```
            trigger orderTrigger on Order (after update) {
                
                if(trigger.isUpdate){
                    if(trigger.isAfter) {
                        OrderHelper.AfterUpdate(trigger.new,trigger.old);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is OrderHelper

```
            public  class OrderHelper  {

                /**
                 * @name AfterUpdate
                 * @description 
                 * @param List<Order> newList
                 * @param List<Order> oldList
                 * @return void
                **/
                public static void AfterUpdate(List<Order> newList, List<Order> oldList){
                    Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
                    for ( Integer i=0; i<newList.size(); i++ ){
                        System.debug('new status==='+newList[i].Status);
                        System.debug('old status'+oldList[i].Status);
                        if ( newList[i].Status == Constants.ACTIVATED_ORDER_STATUS && oldList[i].Status == Constants.DRAFT_ORDER_STATUS ){
                            orderIds.add(newList[i].Id);
                        }
                    }
                    RollUpOrderItems(orderIds);
                }

                /**
                 * @name RollUpOrderItems
                 * @description Given a set of Activated Order ids, query the child Order Items and related Products to calculate Inventory levels
                 * @param Set<Id> activatedOrderIds
                 * @return void
                **/
                public static void RollUpOrderItems(Set<Id> activatedOrderIds){
                    System.debug('Ids==='+activatedOrderIds);
                    Map<Id,Product2> productMap = new Map<Id,Product2>();
                    Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
                    for(OrderItem orderItemRec : [SELECT Id,Product2Id FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId IN: activatedOrderIds]){
                        productIds.add(orderItemRec.Product2Id);
                    }
                    System.debug('productIds==='+productIds);
                    productMap = new Map<Id,Product2>([SELECT Id,Initial_Inventory__c,Quantity_Ordered__c,Quantity_Remaining__c FROM Product2 where Id IN: productIds]);
                    AggregateResult[] result = [Select Product2Id,SUM(Quantity) from OrderItem where Product2Id IN: productMap.keySet() Group By Product2Id ];
                    System.debug('result===='+result);
                    for(AggregateResult ar : result){
                        Id productId = (Id)ar.get('Product2Id');
                        Integer totalQuantityOrdered = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
                        if(productMap.get(productId) != null){
                            productMap.get(productId).Quantity_Ordered__c = totalQuantityOrdered;
                        }
                    }
                    if(productMap != null && productMap.size() > 0) {
                     update productMap.values();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Product2Helper code

```
            public without sharing class Product2Helper {

                /**
                 * @name COLLABORATION_GROUP
                 * @description List of CollaborationGroup used in both business and test logic
                **/
                static List<CollaborationGroup> COLLABORATION_GROUP = [
                    SELECT Id
                    FROM CollaborationGroup
                    WHERE Name = :constants.INVENTORY_ANNOUNCEMENTS
                    OR Name = :('TEST'+constants.INVENTORY_ANNOUNCEMENTS)
                    LIMIT 1
                ];

                /**
                 * @name afterUpdate
                 * @description called by product2 Trigger on After Update
                 * @param List<Product2> newList
                 * @param List<Product2> oldList
                **/
                public static void AfterUpdate(List<Product2> oldList,List<Product2> newList){
                    
                    //ToDo: Declare a List of Product2 records named needsAnnouncement
                    List<Product2> needsAnnouncement = new List<Product2>();

                    //ToDo: Declare a Map of Strings to Inventory_Setting__mdt records
                    //ToDo: Loop through a query of Inventory_Setting__mdt records and populate the Map with Name as the key
                    Map<String,Inventory_Setting__mdt> invSettings =  inventory_Setting__mdt.getAll();
                    
                    //ToDo: Loop through the Products in newList
                    // Use the corresponding Inventory Setting record to determine the correct Low Quantity Alert
                    // If the Product's Quantity Remaining has been changed to less than the Low Quantity Alert
                    //      add it to the needsAnnouncement list
                    
                    for (Integer i=0; i<oldList.size() ; i++){
                        if ( oldList.get(i).Quantity_Remaining__c != newList.get(i).Quantity_Remaining__c){
                            for(Inventory_Setting__mdt inv: invSettings.values()){
                                if( newList.get(i).family == inv.DeveloperName && newList.get(i).Quantity_Remaining__c < inv.Low_Quantity_Alert__c){
                                    needsAnnouncement.add(newList.get(i));
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }

                    //ToDo: Pass records to the postAlerts method
                    PostAlerts(needsAnnouncement);
                }


                /**
                 * @name postAlerts
                 * @description called by product2 Trigger on After Update
                 * @param List<Product2> productList
                **/
                public static void PostAlerts(List<Product2> productList){
                    List<ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput> toPost = new List<ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput>();
                    for ( Product2 p : productList ){
                        // ToDo: Construct a new AnnouncementInput for the Chatter Group so that it:
                        // expires in a day
                        // does not notify users via email.
                        // and has a text body that includes the name of the product followed by the INVENTORY_LEVEL_LOW constant
                        ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput a = new ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput();
                        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
                        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();

                        a.expirationDate = System.Today()+1;
                        a.sendEmails = false;
                        a.parentId = COLLABORATION_GROUP.get(0).Id;
                        textSegmentInput.text= p.Name + ' ' + Constants.INVENTORY_LEVEL_LOW;
                        messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput>();
                        messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
                        a.body = messageBodyInput;
                        toPost.Add(a);
                    }
                    // ToDo: Create and enqueue an instance of the announcementQueuable class with the list of Products
                    AnnouncementQueueable a = new AnnouncementQueueable();
                    a.toPost = toPost;

                    System.enqueueJob(a);
                }
            }
```

Can someone let me know what is causing the error and resolution?

Thanks in advance
Fiona

Comment: can you also post `Product2Helper` code ?

Comment: updated the post with the ```Product2Helper``` code

Comment: I think i got the clue you are missing some steps in your Product2Helper.AfterUpdate() let me confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in your `Product2Helper.AfterUpdate()`

**For Loop**

why are you using for loop with `i` variable when we have `for each` loop that we can easily use to iterate over a list, also there is nesting for loops in your for code, as optimization part this is not good you should minimize using nested for loop

Below is more optimized version for your `Product2Helper.AfterUpdate()`

```
 public static void AfterUpdate(List<Product2> newList, List<Product2> oldList){
        
        //ToDo: Declare a List of Product2 records named needsAnnouncement
        List<Product2> needsAnnouncement = new List<Product2>();
        
        //ToDo: Declare a Map of Strings to Inventory_Setting__mdt records
        Map<String,Inventory_Setting__mdt> inventorySettings = new Map<String,Inventory_Setting__mdt>();
        
        //ToDo: Loop through a query of Inventory_Setting__mdt records and populate the Map with Name as the key
        for (Inventory_Setting__mdt inventorySetting : [SELECT Id, Low_Quantity_Alert__c, QualifiedApiName, DeveloperName, MasterLabel FROM Inventory_Setting__mdt]) {
            inventorySettings.put(inventorySetting.DeveloperName, inventorySetting);
        }
        
        //ToDo: Loop through the Products in newList
        // Use the corresponding Inventory Setting record to determine the correct Low Quantity Alert
        // If the Product's Quantity Remaining has been changed to less than the Low Quantity Alert
        // add it to the needsAnnouncement list
        for(Product2 newProd : newList) {
            if(inventorySettings.get(newProd.family)!= null &&
               newProd.Quantity_Remaining__c < inventorySettings.get(newProd.family).Low_Quantity_Alert__c) {
                   needsAnnouncement.add(newProd);
               }
        }
        
        
        //ToDo: Pass records to the postAlerts method
        PostAlerts(needsAnnouncement);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps